# VBA String Search for Contains a Number

Tags: excel, vba, string-search

I'm doing a data quality check on a large column of strings (ie. Last Name) and want to see if they contain a number.

The VBA code that I've tried so far should be straight forward: if the LastName field contains 1 or 2 (etc.) than the ReasonCode = 3. Later on, if ReasonCode = 3, the results spits out "Contains a number"

However, in situations like 'marshall', it's still populating "Contains a number"

```
ElseIf LastName Like "*#*" Or FirstName Like "*#*" Then

ReasonCode = 3

End If

ElseIf ReasonCode = 3 Then

    Cells(RowT, 16).Value = "Contains a number"

ReasonCode = 0

End If
```

Comment: You need to include more of your code - it's impossible to tell what's happening from just these two lines. My guess is you're not resetting `ReasonCode` so it is still containing a previous value.

Comment: Also use `#` to match a single digit to simplify the first line - see the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) docs for more.

Comment: @BigBen Funnily enough, the code originally had # but was giving the same results so I changed it to the like "*1*" etc. version as I wasn't familiar with #. I changed it back to # to match a single digit but again, it's still giving me "Contains a number" for cases that definitely do not contain a number.

Comment: @dwirony I will edit the code in a moment. I added a reset but it's still giving me issues.

Comment: I'd add more code than what you currently have. I agree with @dwirony's original comment - we need to see more. `Like` shouldn't be the issue. For example, if you enter `? "marshall" Like "*#*"` in the Immediate Window, you'll get `False`. I would think your reset should be at the beginning of the loop too.

Comment: @BigBen moving the reset to the beginning fixed everything. Sorry, I facepalmed.

Comment: Well, easy fix! Glad to help out.

Answer (score 2):

[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853) pretty much [answered your question on the usage of `#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928197/vba-string-search-for-contains-a-number#comment98510092_55928197) with the `Like` operator, so I won't really go into that. But what I did notice is your usage of many Like operators in your If statement, so I figured I would take the opportunity to share a function I created a while ago and use frequently.

The purpose of this function is to reduce multiple `Like` statements when comparing against a single value. While this function doesn't address your specific issue, it may be helpful in the future.

```
Function OrLike(ByVal compareVar As Variant, ParamArray CompareArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    If IsArray(CompareArgs(0)) Then
        For i = LBound(CompareArgs(0)) To UBound(CompareArgs(0))
            If compareVar Like CompareArgs(0)(i) Then
                OrLike = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For i = LBound(CompareArgs) To UBound(CompareArgs)
            If compareVar Like CStr(CompareArgs(i)) Then
                OrLike = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

First, the function checks the first value used in `CompareArgs`. If this value is an array, then it compares against the array, otherwise it will utilize the `ParamArray` keyword. This allows you to use this function in two ways:

## With an Array variable as your arguments

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Array("Blah*", "Blah2*")

If Orlike("BlahBlah", Arr) Then
    ' . . .
End If
```

## Utilizing ParamArray

```
If OrLike("BlahBlah", "Blah*", "Blah2*") Then
    ' . . .
End If
```

---

Obviously, you don't want to use your current If statement that you provided. But if you were as an example, take a look how this function simplifies your statement and vastly improves readability by turning this:

```
ElseIf LastName Like "*1*" Or LastName Like "*2*" Or LastName Like "*3*" Or LastName Like "*4*" _
            Or LastName Like "*5*" Or LastName Like "*6*" Or LastName Like "*7*" _
            Or LastName Like "*8*" Or LastName Like "*9*" Or LastName Like "*0*" Then
```

Into this:

```
ElseIf OrLike(LastName, "*1*", "*2*", "*3*", "*4*", "*5*", "*6*", "*7*", "*8*", "*9*", "*0*") Then
```

---

Not only does it improve readability, but it may actually increase performance. The problem with VBA `If...Then` statements is that everything in the line must be evaluated, even after a statement that returns `True`.

This function takes all of these arguments, and evaluates each statement until one becomes `True`, then it immediately exits the function - ignoring the remaining arguments.